# use go get command, report open "Go\src\runtime\internal\sys\zversion.go" the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: go

the commands are as follows:

`$ go get github.com/beego/bee`

and the result is :

go: open C:\Go\src\runtime\internal\sys\zversion.go: The system cannot find the file specified.

where goes wrong?

Comment: Please show what `go get -v -x github.com/beego/bee` outputs. In general: Always run failing command with a sensible amount of verbosity and debug logging turned on when asking someone for help.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have defined GOPATH or GOROOT.

GOPATH -> The directory where your GoLang work on your computer will be located (your own user specific)

GOROOT -> Displays the GoLang installed directory (for all users) on your computer.

Get help [here](https://beego.me/) to install Beego framework

go get github.com/astaxie/beego

Comment: If you do not have git(https://git-scm.com/) installed, you may encounter the same problem again